# Highcahrts links and button in tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to trigger a click event from inside the tooltip.
I placed the button with a click event inside it and it is not working.
Also I tried to have an external link inside the tooltip. it is also not working.  I am able to get the styling of the elements but not the click event triggered.

here is the tooltip config

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
      pointerEvents: 'auto'
    },
    formatter: function(e) {
        return '<div>'+this.x + ': ' + this.y +'<br><a href="www.google.com">Click Me</a><br><button onclick="clicked()" >Hello</button></div>'
    }
}
```

Here is something I have tried till now: http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/eytroh53/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of security reasons, Highcharts by default filter all HTML that is added through the chart options structure. The `onclick` attribute is potentially risky, so it is filtered out.

To be able to use `onclick` attribute, add it to the `allowedAttributes` table:

```
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('onclick');
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/om32w81g/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/security

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.AST#.allowedAttributes